# Vuejs button multiple clicked

Tags: vue.js

When I put the button in the cards coming from the loop, the loop runs as many as the number of cards it clicks. How can I prevent this

Click on the incoming card, along with the modals on all cards.

When I click it, all the cards' modals are opened. how can i solve ? Thanks.

Comment: You should add more code...

Comment: maybe you can add a `v-once` [directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) to your button. But yes like Michal said, more code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

if you need that a single element **must be** clicked at most once this is the best solution.

```html
    <!-- the click event will be triggered at most once -->
    <a v-on:click.once="doThis"></a>
```

[**docs : vue/event handling**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: Not for after clicking, it opens up how many opened in the loop when you click